# How to install numpy1.9 to python3.4 on Windows?

Tags: python, numpy

I downloaded numpy1.9.0 but there is no EXE file in the package, how should I install it?

Comment: Can you tell where did you download it from ?

Comment: downloaded form http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/  the fie [Download numpy-1.9.0.zip (4.5 MB)]

Comment: Download this http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.0/numpy-1.9.0-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe/download  Mostly you have downloaded numpy source

Comment: If you are looking for compiled packages this is the best place I've found: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Answer (score 1):

Numpy must be compiled for your system. You'll have to use a compiler to compile it if you want to use it from a download of the source code.

For compatibility with your system and other related or dependant packages, I recommend using a prepackaged distribution. (I get most of the Python data stack on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install python-statsmodels`.) For people with **Windows** who come to our Python meetup group and who have trouble installing things, we typically recommend getting the Python data stack distribution, **[Anaconda, from Continuum Analytics](http://continuum.io/downloads#py34)** which will include Numpy. This link should take you to the versions for Python 3.4.

I would much rather you get everything you're likely to need at once as opposed to installing piecemeal different packages from various sources that may not work well together. If you just install Numpy, you're likely to want other packages that depend on it later, which is likely to give you problems if you're not using a package manager. I am unaware of a package manager for Windows, and it's probably out of scope to look for one.

(Disclaimer, Continuum Analytics sometimes sponsors and provides speakers for our meetup group, but I'm just a volunteer, and otherwise unconnnected to them.)

Comment: There's also [Winpython](https://winpython.github.io/), a portable python distribution will less complexity.